# See permission of an raw apk-file

Tags: android

I have an apk in my raw folder. I can start the installation procedure by:

```
            Uri installUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sample.apk"));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(installUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Before I start it I want to show the permission. Is it possible to see the permission before (!) starting the android installation dialog?

Thanks, best regards.

Answer (score -1):

During Installation Android will display the permissions. If you are trying to show this again, this will be duplication of information.

Comment: Hey thanks, but this is what I do not want: start the native installation process.